# Visual composer vc_grid > failed_to_get_id

Tags: visual-composer

I'm facing a problem with Visual Composer and media grid since last weeks. Media grid is not showing images and can't find why. So I've made a page test with this shortcode in admin :

```
[vc_row][vc_column][vc_media_grid grid_id="vc_gid:1598480436378-7a2a9a4f-c137-2" include="107333,107285,107273"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

And here is the code we can see in page front in the div data :

```
{"page_id":107353,"style":"all","action":"vc_get_vc_grid_data","shortcode_id":"{\"failed_to_get_id\":\"vc_gid:1598480436378-7a2a9a4f-c137-2\"}","tag":"vc_media_grid"}
```

I also made a specific page template with this code :

```
do_shortcode('[vc_media_grid grid_id="vc_gid:1598480436378-7a2a9a4f-c137-2" include="107333,107285,107273"]');
```

Same result > shortcode failed to get id

The website is running under WordPress 5.4. I cannot say if that occurred after one update of plugin or WordPress.

Visual composer is not up to date (v5), tried to update to v6, but this break the website.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem on v5. Updating to 6.5 sorted it.